# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError error while lauching sdkmanager.bat from cmd for Android Sdk installation

Tags: android, selenium, sdk, appium

I have downloaded sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip file from official website and extracted in a folder. But I am facing below issue while opening sdkmanager.bat from cmd.

> Error : Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError         at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodH
>   andleNatives.java:383)         at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.InstallAction.register(InstallActi
>   on.java:46)         at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.(Sdk
>   ManagerCliSettings.java:65)         at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.j
>   ava:57)         at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.j
>   ava:48) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method:
>   java.lang.invoke.Lam
>   bdaMetafactory.metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,Meth
>   odType)CallSite/invokeStatic         at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:765)
>   at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:882
>   )         at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.jav
>   a:1018)         at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(Method
>   Handles.java:1322)         at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodH
>   andleNatives.java:381)         ... 4 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metaf
>   actory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invok
>   e/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/l
>   ang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;         at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)         at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:854)
>   at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:879
>   )         ... 7 more

Comment: Try to installed the Android studio.you will get the sdk manager in the tools section itself(Path -> Tools<Android<SDK Manager).

Answer (score 0):

I installed the whole Android Studio that comes with the SDK Manager.

Others seem to have solved this by updating Java or installing the latest Java jdk.

If that doesnt help post your Java version here.